# Trouble accessing profile on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I created my profile earlier this afternoon and everything was looking good.  After a dinner break and came back and tried to make some changes, and I got the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" screen when I clicked the 'edit' link for a number or items on the profile.  Now I'm seeing that screen when I click on the "my profile" tab.  I can't even view my profile.  Help!

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about that.  A service went down and Careers didn't handle it well.  Everything should be working now.